# The application named HTTPS://test113.onmicrosoft.com/FTP was not found in the tenant named test113.onmicrosoft.com

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have to authenticate an application against Azure AD. I have created the web API and added it to the Azure AD application section. Changed the manifest file, created a web API and authenticated with the Azure AD and created a Windows form, containing the following code:

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string authority = "https://login.windows.net/test113.onmicrosoft.com";
    string resourceURI = "https://test113.onmicrosoft.com/ftp";
    string clientID = "5177ef76-cbb4-43a8-a7d0-899d3e886b34";
    Uri returnURI = new Uri("http://keoftp");

    AuthenticationContext authContext =
        new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    AuthenticationResult authResult =
        authContext.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientID, returnURI);

    string authHeader = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

    // don't do this in prod
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((s, c, c2, se) => true);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:44300/api/tasks");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
}
```

I have got an exception:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: AADSTS50001: The application named
>   https://test113.onmicrosoft.com/ftp was not found in the tenant named
>   test113.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not
>   been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by
>   any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication
>   request to the wrong tenant.
>
> Trace ID: e782d60e-b861-46a3-b32b-f3df78396bd0 
>   Correlation ID:
>   b4809815-2755-4de1-bd1b-0221d74fd0f0 Timestamp: 2016-03-17 11:20:08Z

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `https://test113.onmicrosoft.com/ftp` as the resourceURI. Usually, I use `https://management.core.windows.net/` for Azure Service Management, and `https://graph.windows.net` for Graph API.

Comment: FYI: It worked. After i have added the client id of the application that uses my APIs in Authorized client application section  of my API app in the  Azure Portal. Azure Portal | App Registration| Expose an API, Add Client Application in Authorized Client Application.

Answer (score 11):

Resource in the request means the resource which you want to access in the particular tenant. When a native client needs to get a token from Azure Active Directory, it needs to specify the resource it wants a token for. In this scenario the client application wants access to the Web API so the **APP ID URI for the Web API is used as the resource name**. After it has the token it also needs to know the URL where the resource can be accessed, in this case the address of the Web API.For example:

```
// Resource settings this application wants to access
private string resource = "https://cloudalloc.com/CloudAlloc.WebAPI";
private Uri WebAPIUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44313");
```

Both of these settings can be found in the single sign-on section of the CONFIGURE page for the Web API application in the Azure Management portal.

Click [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-3-developing-native-client-applications/) for more details .

Comment: Hi Nan, all i can see in the configure section is name, clientid,redirecturils and logo. i am unable to see APP ID URI

Comment: Just wanted to mention that i am using NATIVE CLIENT APPLICATION

Comment: @Rinu,that app id is in web api configure page .